# fluid rows not diplaying properly bootstrap 3 + mvc4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, row

I have recently started to learn to use bootstrap with Mvc4 and have the following problem:

I am trying to make a standard layout that will look something like this:

[image]

the navbar is in a layout.

the view that contains the content is:

```
@model BootstrapTest4.Models.Menu

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- rows -->
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Payment Taken
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Default
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Approved
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="error">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            02/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Declined
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            03/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Pending
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            04/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Call in to confirm
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Payment Taken
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Default
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Approved
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="error">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            02/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Declined
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            03/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Pending
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            04/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Call in to confirm
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-- End of Rows -->
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

the browsers render this in the following way:
[image]

this is the source from the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- rows -->
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Payment Taken
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Default
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Approved
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="error">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            02/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Declined
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            03/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Pending
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            04/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Call in to confirm
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Payment Taken
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Default
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Approved
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="error">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            02/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Declined
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            03/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Pending
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            04/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Call in to confirm
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-- End of Rows -->
    </div>


</body>
</html>

          </div>
          <div id="Footer">
              Insert footer
          </div>
    </div>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it appears that i was using the wrong class for the columns.

instead of span2 i should have used col-md-2 and so on.

the view ended up looking like this:

```
@model BootstrapTest4.Models.Menu

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- rows -->
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Payment Taken
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Default
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Approved
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="error">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            02/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Declined
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            03/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Pending
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            04/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Call in to confirm
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Payment Taken
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Default
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            01/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Approved
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="error">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            02/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Declined
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            03/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Pending
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TB - Monthly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            04/04/2012
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Call in to confirm
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-- End of Rows -->
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```